# Period matrix of abelian surface

Tags: complex-geometry, abelian-varieties

Let's construct a complex torus as $(\mathbb{C}^\times)^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$, where the $\mathbb{Z}^2$-action is generated by
$$
(z_1,z_2)\mapsto(az_1,bz_2), \ \ \ (z_1,z_2)\mapsto(cz_1,dz_2). 
$$
My question is, what is the period matrix of this complex torus? I initially thought it is given by $\left[{\begin{array}{cc} \log a & \log b \\ \log c & \log d \ \end{array} } \right]$, but this is in general not symmetric. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you wrote is fine if $b=c$.

Comment: >Michael Why isn't this an action of $\mathbb{Z}^2$?

Comment: @user64726: I was mistaken. Sorry.